# How do I get notified on new members on my Google Group?

Tags: notifications, google-groups, access-control

I am the admin on a Google Group. I want to be notified every time a new member signs up. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this possible, you could change the permissions on your Group so that they have to request access to the Group.  That way you will know when someone wants to join your Group as you will have to authorise their access.

Comment: But even that has the same problem: How do I get an email notifying me that there are join requests?  Currently, it seems I have to log-in every day to check.